# Can I use identity as a parameter for a function in a column default constraint?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `MyTable` with the columns `Id, OtherId, HashID`

I also have a t-sql function called `hashids.encode2B`. This function takes two values in, and gives a AZaz09 encoded "hash" out.

Is there anyway I can use the `encode2B` function as the default value for the `HashID` column, while also using `Id` and `OtherID` as the parameters for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create calculated column.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION fn_test 
    (
        -- Add the parameters for the function here
        @id int, @id2 int
    )
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN

        RETURN @id + @id2

    END
    GO



    CREATE TABLE MyTable
    (
        Id INT,
        OtherId INT,
        HashId AS dbo.fn_test(id, otherid) 
    )

    INSERT INTO MyTable (id, OtherId) VALUES (1,2);

    SELECT * FROM MyTable;

Id  OtherId HashId
1   2   3
```

Comment: It's as easy as that... This is how it goes when my brain doesn't come up with the right terms to google. :)